# Why does interpolation does not work if I'm getting the expected result in the Console?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make a Countdown in Vue.js but the interpolation is not working and I cannot understand why.

I have declared this:

```
data() {
  return {
    dueDate: '' 
  }   
},
```

And I'm trying to show it here:

```
<div id="app">
  {{ dueDate }}
</div>
```

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/chechocz/pen/ExYQEQM

In the console I'm getting the expected result but it doesn't interpolate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `this` value will not be correct inside the `setInterval` function. Use an arrow function instead.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that! Thank You very much! Worked as it should!